# Add and remove check and input boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add and remove input and check boxes from my form but the examples I have come across won't allow me to add these with my own with custom text. How do I achieve this using JQuery?

Here is my template: https://jsfiddle.net/cg1uoh9w/4/

Here is one of the examples: http://jsfiddle.net/KPkJn/9/

```
<!-- -->

<div class="sub-container-title">This is what I want to appear above the first box</div>

<ul class="no-style">
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" name="text_area" class="text_area added" maxlength="50" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">remove</button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- -->

<div class="sub-container-title">This is what I want to appear above the second box</div>

<ul class="no-style">
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">remove</button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so what have you tried? you have a great example for reference what doesn't work?

Comment: I can incorporate the example into mine but as you can see in my fiddle, I have a textbox to allow custom text to be added to the appended items. This I can not achieve.

Comment: So what have you tried? your fiddle doesn't have any jquery. show some effort before asking for help

Comment: Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you do it...

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="add_input_field" class="add_input_field" placeholder="Write input name"><input type="submit" name="add_input_submit" class="add_input_submit"><br />
  <input type="text" name="add_checkbox_field" class="add_checkbox_field" placeholder="Write checkbox name"><input type="submit" name="add_checkbox_submit" class="add_checkbox_submit"><br />
</div>
<div class="new_fields_container">
</div>
```

Thats the regular HTML look at the **class** tags on both the submit button and the text fields.

Then with jQuery

```
$('.add_input_submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input_name = $('.add_input_field').val();
  var remove_name = input_name.split(' ').join('_');

  $('.new_fields_container').append('<div new_input="' + remove_name + '"><input type="text" name="' + input_name + '" placeholder="' + input_name + '">' + input_name + '<input type="submit" class="remove" new_input_name="'+ remove_name +'" value="remove"><br /></div>');
});

$('.add_checkbox_submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input_name = $('.add_checkbox_field').val();
  var remove_name = input_name.split(' ').join('_');


  $('.new_fields_container').append('<div new_input="' + remove_name + '"><input type="checkbox" name="' + input_name + '" value="' + input_name + '"> ' + input_name + '<input type="submit" class="remove" new_input_name="'+ remove_name +'" value="remove"><br /></div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input_name = $(this).attr('new_input_name');
  $('[new_input='+input_name+']').remove();
});
```

The jQuery is listening for the click on the submit buttons depending on the **class name** for example the **$('.add_input_submit')**.

The **.val();** is actually reading the input field, so the name you want it and saving it on a variable, then you can included on the HTML that you will create on the next steps.

The **event.preventDefault();** will stop the "form" to be submitted literally (jQuery doesn't need to submit the actual form since is listening to the clicks all the time).

The **.append()** is adding the actual HTML code (So your new input values) to the dynamic div you selected in this case **new_fields_container**

**REMOVE**

Now to remove I added the **$('body').on('click', '.remove'** this .click is different because it needs to listen to ajax generated element, that's why it will parse the whole **body** of the site to listen for a click.

I also added the **remove** button to the generated HTML and added a **div** container to every new field.

Now the **.remove();** will search for the **div** with the **new_input=""** attribute and it will remove it.

Heres the code

**UPDATED WITH REMOVE**:

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/eljamz/44gnhcan/6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about removing added elements?

Comment: I just updated the Answer with the remove... I forgot to add that!, hope it helps to understand how is everything working and why.

Comment: It's not functioning on my side.

Comment: Check the Fiddle it's working... BUT if you create a field with 2 separated words, it will never find it... I think you can figure this one out... just do a str.replace on the input name to never leave spaces on the classes thats all you need.

Comment: So replace all the spaces with a underscore... so **"Example One"** will be added on the div container name as **"example_one"**, and you will be good to go

Comment: I understand but for removing the input and check box it does not work.

Comment: Actually I fixed the multiple words issue... you mean both checkboxes and text inputs at the same time??? send me a chat if you want...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123994/discussion-between-user2680614-and-eljamz).

Comment: I sent you a chat